# Objective-C. access to property of item in array which consists of objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I have the array which consists of objects:

```
ViewController *item1 = [ViewController new];
item1.name = @"Mary";
item1.Description = @"good girl";
ViewController *item2 = [ViewController new];
item2.name = @"Daniel";
item2.Description = @"bad boy";
ComplexArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects: item1, item2, nil];`
```

i want to view in labels a name and description if name is equal Mary

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ComplexArray count]; i++) {
    if (item[i].name isEqualString:@"Mary") {
        _nameLabel.text= item[i].name;
        _DescriptionLabel.text= item[i].Description;
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: you didn't assign the  ComplexArray[i] in your item named variable inside the loop. You need to assign, ComplexArray[i] in item. See my solution. However, why are you using objective -C and swift syntax together. Please be caution, you should try to code in one language.

Comment: @Natasha There is no `Swift` syntax in the code samples.

Comment: @Losiowaty, as far as, I know, we don't access elements from array in Objective-C like item[i]. It should be like [item objectAtIndex:i]. Pardon me if I am wrong but I have checked into apple's document, and I believe, that is not a objective-C statement. Besides, there is the statement "ViewController *item1 = [ViewController new]", this also doesn't seem right. To initialize a ViewController, we need to do [[ViewController alloc] init], unless this statement is not initializing, it doesn't seem to be the right way in Objective C.

Comment: Here you can read about `new` keyword - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html , and here about indexed subscripts - http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/ .

Comment: As i cannot edit my previous comment - `new` isn't a keyword, it is a class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you didn't assign anything in `item` variable. Just update like this and it will work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ComplexArray count]; i++) {
    ViewController *item = [ComplexArray objectAtIndex:i]; // you missed this line.
    if ([item.name isEqualToString:@"Mary"]) { //you missed the opening "[" and closing "]"
        _nameLabel.text= item.name;
        _DescriptionLabel.text= item.Description;
    }
}
```

Comment: `item[i].name == "Mary"`?  Nope.

Comment: @Droppy, yes you are right. I presumed it was swift. Now I edited the answer in objective C.

Comment: better to use `for (ViewController *item in ComplexArray) {`, you don't need the index

Answer (score 1):

You basically had it.  All I did was rename `item` to `ComplexArray` added `[]` around the `isEqualToString` call and added a `break`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ComplexArray count]; i++) {
    ViewController *item = ComplexArray[i];
    if ([item.name isEqualString:@"Mary"]) {
        _nameLabel.text= item.name;
        _DescriptionLabel.text= item.Description;
        break;    // Added
    }
}
```

There are other ways, but this approach is fine.

BTW: variables should start, by convention, with a lowercase character.

Comment: Droppy,i have error: property 'name' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: As yes; you will have to tell the compiler what object is contained in the array.  Let me correct my answer.

Comment: It is just a matter of coding convention, but I feel that it would be better, if we follow one language in one project, unless we have mix. So, just my suggestion, you could edit the "ViewController *item = ComplexArray[i];" to  ViewController *item = [ComplexArray objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: @Natasha I disagree.  Objective-C literals and array/dictionary subscripting has been in the language for quite some time now.  They are convenient and easy to read.